# Port Android App to Desktop?

Tags: android

I'm just wondering if it would be possible (and legal) to port an Android app to desktop?
I'm creating an android game that would work well on PC too (even with the cellphone like layout) and was thinking that maybe I could 'embed' an android emulator with an installer or would that process be a bit hard for a novice Java coder?

Comment: the legality depends on the license. android itself is open source, and if the app is also open source, then yes it's legal to convert it to a desktop app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep the application logic separate from Android contructs (activites, intents etc) it should be easy to create Java Swing UI for the desktop app and thus have a common codebase. I have written Java code that is platform agnostic that works on J2ME/BlackBerry/Android and with a bit of design it is not at all hard to do so.

Comment: Well I have both openGL and android UI components in my game.
I guess I could just use jogl in replace for android opengl lib (not sure how similar they are) but doing all that just makes me wonder if it wouldn't be 'easier'/smarter to recreate the whole app for desktop.

Comment: For me this kind of system worked well when I have multiple applications to create. I agree, for one off case it may be a better idea to just recreate the whole app for desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your code to use libGDX - http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/. You can maintain the same codebase and deploy simultaneously to Android and the Desktop (Windows, Linux, Mac). You will however need to convert your UI system to an OpenGL based UI. libGDX itself has a nice UI system which you can use. If not for this app, you can use it for future ones.